# What is my file-system-name and storage-account-name? And how do I find it?

Tags: databricks

I am trying to connect databricks to my blob containers in azure data lake gen2.

I can't find what my file-system-name is or my storage-account-name is anywhere for a connection.

dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://file-system-name@storage-account-name.dfs.core.windows.net/")

Thanks. If someone could reference an example that would be great.

Answer (score 7):

Oh man ! they could have provided a better documentation with an example. took some time to click it

file-system-name means the container name. For instance if you have a container 'data' created in a storage account "myadls2021", it would be like below.

val data = spark.read
.option("header", "true")
.csv("abfss://data@myadls2021.dfs.core.windows.net/Baby_Names__Beginning_2007.csv")

Comment: Indeed. Documentation needs to be improved. The FileSystemName here in DatalakeUriBuilder also means blob container name when used for Azure blob storage account.  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.datalake.datalakeuribuilder.filesystemname?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 1):

file-system-name is the container name. storage-account-name is the azure storage account. Refer image below.

[image]

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "abfss://raw@storageaccadls01.dfs.core.windows.net/",
  mount_point = "/mnt/raw",
  extra_configs = configs)
```

Can access the storage account files from the dbfs mount point location. Refer image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend following this documentation :
https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2.html#azure-data-lake-storage-gen2
It explains how to access and/or mount an Azure Datalake Gen2 from Databricks.